# Mixing code errors

Tags: javascript, php, html

Ok, I have a basic all-in-one page for my user profiles on my site like so:

```
<?php

if($_GET['p']=='pb'){

echo '<p>pb</p>';

}elseif($_GET['p']=='example2'){

echo '<p>Example Two';

}elseif($_GET['p']=='example1'){

echo '<p>Example One';

}else{
echo '<h3>Page not defined&#59 error!</h3>';

}

?>
```

I am having issues with some inline javascript though, when I try to add a onclick="location.href='' the php confuses it. I've tried adding \' to the front and back, but it doesn't seem to work, here is what I have:

```
<?php

if($_GET['p']=='pb'){

echo '<p>pb</p>';

}elseif($_GET['p']=='example2'){

echo '
<h1>Example Link One</h1>
<p>You clicked Example Link One!</p>
<table border="0" cellspacing="15" width="100%">
<tr>
<td bgcolor="grey" onclick="location.href=\''/media/profiles/person/'\'">
<p>HOME</p>
</td>
</tr>
</table>';

}elseif($_GET['p']=='example1'){

echo '
<h1>Example Link One</h1>
<p>You clicked Example Link One!</p>
<table border="0" cellspacing="15" width="100%">
<tr>
<td bgcolor="grey" onclick="location.href=\''/media/profiles/person/'\'">
<p>HOME</p>
</td>
</tr>
</table>';

}else{
echo '<h3>Page not defined&#59 error!</h3>';

}

?>
```

But I still get several errors, including:
-Use of undefined constant media - assumed 'media'
-Warning: Division by zero
-Notice: Use of undefined constant profiles - assumed 'profiles'
-Notice: Use of undefined constant person - assumed 'person'
So on and so forth.

I know it what it has to do with, but how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your quoting is wrong. You are escaping the first single quote but with another one following imediatly. This second one is interpreted by php as the end of string which is not what you intended. Just remove this 2nd single quotes and it should fix your errors.

```
echo '
<h1>Example Link One</h1>
<p>You clicked Example Link One!</p>
<table border="0" cellspacing="15" width="100%">
<tr>
<td bgcolor="grey" onclick="location.href=\'/media/profiles/person/\'">
<p>HOME</p>
</td>
</tr>
</table>';
```

Edit: Also worth mentioning: If you have a string with mixed quotes it is often easier to use [heredoc style](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc)

```
$str = <<<EOD
Example of string
spanning multiple lines
using heredoc syntax.
EOD;
```

Comment: You are the second person to suggest heredoc style to me, I'll read up on it.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just close the PHP tags?

```
<?php

if($_GET['p']=='pb'){

echo '<p>pb</p>';

}elseif($_GET['p']=='example2'){

?>
<h1>Example Link One</h1>
<p>You clicked Example Link One!</p>
<table border="0" cellspacing="15" width="100%">
<tr>
<td bgcolor="grey" onclick="javascript:location.href='/media/profiles/person/'">
<p>HOME</p>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<?php

}elseif($_GET['p']=='example1'){

?>
<h1>Example Link One</h1>
<p>You clicked Example Link One!</p>
<table border="0" cellspacing="15" width="100%">
<tr>
<td bgcolor="grey" onclick="javascript:location.href='/media/profiles/person/'">
<p>HOME</p>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<?php

}else{
echo '<h3>Page not defined&#59 error!</h3>';

}

?>
```

Also, it would be more elegant to use a design pattern within your application - This application, if you stick with the "design pattern" you're currently using will become a burden to update and maintain.

Comment: I don't close the tags because have other php codes on the page that would counteract my pages, and it's self maintained by the user. The rest of my site does not use this design pattern.

Comment: also, It's important to mention that these echo's are echoed into the body (or most of it anyway) of the page. I have header and footer pages I use for a universal layout.